# My goodman furnace is not igniting my burners

Tags: furnace

I have a goodman furnace and when it is calling for heat the ignitor comes on and goes off and comes on again and the burners never comes on what could be the problem

Comment: Does the unit display any error codes? Do you hear the gas valve open, and/or gas flowing? How long does the igniter stay on?

Comment: the goodman's often have a built in 4 try limit.  does it energize 4 times in a row and then stop trying, then give you a flashing status light on the PCB?

Comment: When did you last clean out the burner box with a blower, brush or vacuum? Have you run a brass brush over the ignitor tips to get the crud off? It doesn't take much dirt to block the flow of gas to the ignitor.

Comment: For some reason I read this as 'My goddamn furnace..."

Answer (score 1):

No fuel.

Verify that you have gas supplied to the unit.

Also, an automatic gas valve sometimes malfunctions by sticking.  After you have verified that gas is supplied to the unit, give the automatic valve a solid tap with a hammer or a wrench during the start-up cycle to see if it opens.  If so, then you need a new gas valve.  (Do not tap the valve hard enough to damage it.)

Answer (score 0):

Presuming everything is fine with the unit. One setup that commonly creates this condition is use of the blower fan. If you have your fan set to ON at the thermostat instead of being set to AUTO this will cause the furnace to not ignite when called upon. It doesn't matter what speed the blower is running at, but the furnace must have sole control of the fan.

Answer (score 0):

Test for 24v at the gas valve; if you have ample voltage, your gas valve will need to be changed. If you do not have ample voltage at the gas valve you have a wiring or board problem. In any case, have a licensed gas fitter with furnace service experience look at and repair your furnace. I have found this to be the cause in the past as an HVAC professional.

Answer (score 0):

Having checked all of the above, checked to make sure combustion air inlet and exhaust were clear and removed orifices to make sure they were clean,  I inspected burner as it ran. Noticed nozzle that was next to the igniter flared the flame out just a little different than the others. I took manifold off and swapped the first nozzle with the last nozzle and it fixed my intermittent lighting issue. Must have changed the way it blew the gas onto the igniter just enough. The furnace used to bang when it would light as ignition was almost always delayed but now it lights quiet.